# Searching for line of one text file in another text file, faster

Tags: c#, text-files, indexof

Is there a faster way to search each line of one text file for occurrence in another text file, than by going line by line in both files?

I have two text files - one has ~2500 lines (let's call it TxtA), the other has ~86000 lines(TxtB). I want to search TxtB for each line in TxtA, and return the line in TxtB for each match found.

I currently have this setup as: for each line in TxtA, search TxtB line by line for a match. However this is taking a really long time to process. It seems like it would take 1-3 hours to find all the matches.

Here is my code...

```
private static void getGUIDAndType()
    {

        try
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Begin.");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

            String dbFilePath = @"C:\WindowsApps\CRM\crm_interface\data\";
            StreamReader dbsr = new StreamReader(dbFilePath + "newdbcontents.txt");
            List<string> dblines = new List<string>();

            String newDataPath = @"C:\WindowsApps\CRM\crm_interface\data\";
            StreamReader nsr = new StreamReader(newDataPath + "HolidayList1.txt");
            List<string> new1 = new List<string>();

            string dbline;
            string newline;

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            while ((newline = nsr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Reset
                dbsr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
                dbsr.DiscardBufferedData();

                while ((dbline = dbsr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    newline = newline.Trim();
                    if (dbline.IndexOf(newline) != -1)
                    {//if found... get all info for now
                        Console.WriteLine("FOUND: " + newline);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        new1.Add(newline);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {//the first line of db does not contain this line... 
                        //go to next dbline. 
                        Console.WriteLine("Lines do not match - continuing");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Going to next new Line");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //continue;
            }

            nsr.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Writing to dbc3.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\WindowsApps\CRM\crm_interface\data\dbc3.txt", results.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Finished. Press ENTER to continue.");

            Console.WriteLine("End.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:  " + ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if there is a faster way. Preferably something that would  take 5-10 minutes... I've heard of indexing but didn't find much on this for txt files. I've tested regex and it's no faster than indexof. Contains won't work because the lines will never be exactly the same.

Thanks.

Comment: First sorting bigger files then making a binary search on it may help. Or a hash table on bigger file?

Comment: "Is there a faster way ..." - you might start by removing the `Sleep()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Note that I'm assuming it's reasonable to read at least *one* file into memory. You may want to swap the queries below around to avoid loading the "big" file into memory, but even 86,000 lines at (say) 1K per line is going to be less than 2G of memory - which is relatively little to do something significant.

You're reading the "inner" file each time. There's no need for that. Load both files into memory and go from there. Heck, for *exact* matches you can do the whole thing in LINQ easily:

```
var query = from line1 in File.ReadLines("newDataPath + "HolidayList1.txt")
            join line2 in File.ReadLines(dbFilePath + "newdbcontents.txt")
            on line1 equals line2
            select line1;

var commonLines = query.ToList();
```

But for non-joins it's still simple; just read one file completely first (explicitly) and then stream the other:

```
// Eagerly read the "inner" file
var lines2 = File.ReadAllLines(dbFilePath + "newdbcontents.txt");
var query = from line1 in File.ReadLines("newDataPath + "HolidayList1.txt")
            from line2 in lines2
            where line2.Contains(line1)
            select line1;

var commonLines = query.ToList();
```

There's nothing clever here - it's just a really simple way of writing code to read all the lines in one file, then iterate over the lines in the other file and for each line check against all the lines in the first file. But even without anything clever, I *strongly* suspect it would perform well enough for you. Concentrate on simplicity, eliminate unnecessary IO, and see whether that's good enough before trying to do anything fancier.

Note that in your original code, you should be using `using` statements for your `StreamReader` variables, to ensure they get disposed properly. Using the above code makes it simple to not even need that though...

Comment: Since Paul compares two files line by line, reading the bigger file, sort it and making a binary search for every line in smaller file (or creating a hash set) would be much faster.

Comment: @L.B.: I'm not sure that would actually help, given that the match can be anywhere in the line. Also, I'd prefer to keep it simple to start with - and I reckon my approach would be easily fast enough.

Comment: From this sentence `Is there a faster way to search each line of one text file for occurrence in another text file` I only understand a line by line comparison. If it is not and a `contains` is needed you are correct. But I still insist on my downvote

Comment: @L.B. If it's a strict match, then look at my first query, which uses `join` - it'll use a hash set internally, which should be faster than a binary search. If this really is your downvote (on both mine and Tim's solution), it seems entirely unwarranted. I've answered both the "exact match" and "containment match" possible questions efficiently and simply, haven't I?

Comment: Upvoted. Simple, and surely more than *fast enough*. Down-vote = post is un-helpful/misleading/incorrect, do you seriously think that's a fair description of this?

Comment: Hmm... This seems like it would work great. I am getting an error though...

`Error 11 The range variable 'line1' conflicts with a previous declaration of 'line1' C:\Users\LABA-45\Desktop\crm_interface\TestRunForCRMInterface\Program.cs 209 18 TestRunForCRMInterface` 

I don't have "line1" declared elsewhere in my code, it appears to be declaring it in the select portion because that part is not underlined in red. Strangely can't find much for a fix on the net... Thoughts?

Comment: I think there is a problem with this actually... equals or contains will not work because the lines will never be the same. The two files are in almost the same format, except the DB lines have an extra tab and 'field' with 10-20 characters. That's why I was using indexof, because the "HolidayList1" will always be present as a portion of a line in "newdbcontents". Anyway to use Linq and indexof in conjunction here?

Comment: I think I just realized that contains is working for a line, not a .txt document. It should work actually... but I still get the range variable confliction error... :(

Comment: Nevermind! There was a little typo in the code I didn't notice. The second set of code worked like a charm. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 4):

There might be a faster way, but this LINQ apporoach should be faster than 3 hours and is a sight better to read and maintain:

```
var f1Lines    = File.ReadAllLines(f1Path);
var f2LineInf1 = File.ReadLines(f2Path)
                .Where( line => f1Lines.Contains(line))
                .Select(line => line).ToList();
```

**Edit**: tested and required less than 1 second for 400000 lines in file2 and 17000 lines in file1. I can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) for the big file which does not load all into memory at once. For the smaller file i need to use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) since `Contains` needs the complete list of lines of file 1.

If you want to log the result in a third file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(logPath, f2LineInf1);
```

Comment: It is me. See my comments I wrote for Jon Skeet.

Comment: No need to load f2lines all at once. `IEnumerable<string> File.ReadLines()` would use far less mem. (not -1 though).

Comment: @RichardW1001 `I think someone is just down-voting everything`, you think so since it seems you don't read comments.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thanks for mentioning `File.ReadLines`, but that approach was much slower on a quick test. Maybe i've missed something. I keep the answer using ReadAllLines. But anyway, ReadLines might be the better approach.

Comment: Never said it would be faster (:, YMMV.  But when the files are too big for memory it's the only option.

Comment: Hmm... I set the f1Lines as the smaller file and f2LineInF1 as the larger file, but when I run this it creates a txt file with no lines... I searched the larger file for occurrence of one of the lines in the smaller file manually with Ctrl+F in Notepad, and it finds it fine. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

I don't know if it makes a difference, but both files have tab delimited strings... it should still find it fine though...

Comment: @Paul: `f2LineInF1` is not a file but the result of the comparison as `List<String>`(no txt-file) with all lines that are in file2 and file1. So the whole line is equal in both files or only part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty because I've got to go... If you can do it in memory, try working with this snippet:

```
    //string[] searchIn = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");
    //string[] searchFor = File.ReadAllLines("File2.txt");

    string[] searchIn = new string[] {"A","AB","ABC","ABCD", null, "", "    "};
    string[] searchFor = new string[] {"A","BC","BCD", null, "", "   "};

    matchDictionary;

    foreach(string item in file2Content)
    {
        string[] matchingItems = Array.FindAll(searchIn, x => (x == item) || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) ? (x.Contains(item) || item.Contains(x)) : false));
    }
```