# StreamReader in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, file

I am trying to use StreamReader to read a text file and display the results in a textbox, but everytime I try to do that, my textbox ends up freezing. The same result in Console seems to work fine. Here is my code so far.

```
private void ReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string line = "";
     bool IsActive = true;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))
            {
                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = file.ReadLine();
                    textBox1.Text = file.ReadLine();
              }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think in your console you have permissions, but in your application you might be restricted to paths that it has access to. Try creating a folder in your application and put the text file in there. Also, why don't you create a stringbuilder (say StringBuilder sb = new ...) and append your lines to it, then pass the result of reading all the lines as textBox1.text = sb. If you try passing one line at a time to your textbox, you'll end up with only the last line read.

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the textbox in the `while` loop which is most likely locking up the GUI thread (depending on how big your file is), you're also losing some of the original file content.

I would recommend that you build up the file contents using a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and then assign the content of this object outside of the loop, which will optimize the performance.

Example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
   builder.Append(file.ReadLine());
}

textBox.Text = builder.ToString();
```

You could also put the file operation on another `Thread` or `Task` and compare performance.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use that.

Comment: @SmartDeveloper - still use the stream reader (That's how you are getting the file contents).  StringBuilder will keep track of the contents from the file.  You then assign the `builder` object to the textbox (Outside the loop) like I have shown in my answer.

Comment: One last question, is there something I can use while it reads the huge amount of text that I know something is happening in the textbox? There are about 30,000 records in the text file and it completely freezes trying any method.

Comment: @SmartDeveloper - you could look at putting this on a seperate thread so the GUI thread is not locked, I would also display some sort of notification to the user that something is loading in the background.

Answer (score 1):

This post seems pretty old, so not sure if you got it working, but I used something similar in some of my code and I got it to work using

textbox.AppendText(stringName)

Answer (score 0):

This code is very odd:

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    line = file.ReadLine();
    textBox1.Text = file.ReadLine();
}
```

It seems you are overwriting the textbox over and over.  When your code is done running, only the last line will be showing.  Also, you are only displaying every other line, since every other other line is stored in the variable `line` and then discarded without being displayed.

I think you meant

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    textBox1.Text += file.ReadLine();
}
```

or maybe

```
while (!file.EndOfStream)
{
    textBox1.Text += ("\n" + file.ReadLine());
}
```

Also, make sure that textBox1 is set to [Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I ended up doing something like this: 
                    while (!file.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        //Sb.Append(file.ReadLine());
                        textBox1.Text += file.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

                        Application.DoEvents();
                    }

Comment: I am still having trouble with reading a large text file quickly.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to read it one line at a time?

Comment: I have to write the file again in a textfile once I make some changes.

Comment: Textfile to Textbox -> Make Changes -> Write back to Text file.

Answer (score 0):

### Reading it faster

Try reading the whole file at once instead of one line at a time.  All those individual updates to the textbox to add a line will get very slow.

If the file is extremely big, you could also use [ReadToEndAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx), although then you'd have to figure out what to do with the rest of your UX.  Anyway, if the file is that big, you should [probably not be using an ordinary textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517673/c-sharp-best-strategy-to-implement-reader-for-large-text-files).

Note that you may have to do a newline translation from your file to the textbox, depending on the format.  I think the textbox delimits multiline with just `\n\` whereas your filesystem might use `\r\n`.

```
private void ReadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:\\test.txt"))
        {
            var temp = file.ReadToEnd();
            // temp = temp.Replace("\r\n","\n");  You may or may not have to do something like this 
            textBox1.Text = temp;
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "File not found");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: If I read the whole file at once, I cannot read each line then and check if the record is correct or not. As of right now I am reading the file, but as you said large file can cause an issue.